# how to model user - usergroup in relational db with privilege transfers?

Tags: many-to-many, relational-database, acl, rdbms, foreign-key-relationship

I have this problem when designing a simple ACL system:

- `Person 1` from `Team A` could edit `Item X`
- `Person 1` transfers from `Team A` to `Team B`
- `Team B` could not edit `Item X`
- due to historical reasons, we still allow `Person 1` to edit `Item X`

here's what typical model in RDBMS like:

- `Person` table has many-to-many relation with table `Team`
- There's ACL table, which looks like this:
  `object_type | object_id | item_type | item_id | deny_or_allow`

To handle the inter-team transfer like I described

- should i *just* add an extra rule for `Person 1`?
- what happens when someday we deny the entire `Team A` (including ex-members) from editing `ItemX` ?
- Should we keep a person transfer history table as well?
- So to decide the ACL rule, we have to traversal a ton of things, perhaps I even missed a few

This problem complexity grows as ACL and personnel transfers happens all the time. What's the best practice to design the model in a relational DB for this? Are there a general term or topic for these kind of things?

Comment: Any reason not to just add a group called "Former Team A", and add people to it when they transition from Team A to another group?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Suppose another `Person 2` might join & leave `Team A` before `Item X` even existed. This might let the unrelated person touching `Item X`? What I am trying to do is emulating how real-world privileges work. If you are involved with an `Item X` you are always involved, unless your old team is denied together.

Answer (score 0):

Typical table-driven security uses a [role-based security](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/what-is-a-basic-model-for-making-a-database-with-users-and-groups/12107#12107) pattern.

If you want to retain access for people who have left a role then you need to add effective and expiry date/times on the role members and role rights.  This would allow you to say things like "Person 2" left "Team A" before "Item X" existed, so they can't see it.